# How to add parameters when using httppost with beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, html.beginform

Hi I was learning [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial to learn MVC with entity framework. I found that in this example, it has 3 parameters for edit method submitted by beginform() in view page.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formCollection, string[] selectedCourses)
{....}
```

controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

view

I can guess 'string[] selectedCourse' parameter is from the checkbox inside of the fieldset in the form. But I'm still not sure about where does 'int id' comes from. Please give me an idea about how httppost works in MVC

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the URL from the tutorial, you'll see its `/Instructor/Edit/1`. `1` is the `ID` parameter and it maps to the `ID` in the action method when the form is submitted.

Comment: I understand why 'GET' edit() has Id as a parameter. Can you explain me why 'POST' edit() needs id parameter since it already has model as a parameter. And default generated 'Post' edit() method also does not have Id as a parameter.

Comment: Because that one is using the Edit function which I would assume would want to find the specific primary key of your underlying entity. Need to look into your RouteConfig in the App_Start folder as well and that should take care of some of the confusion with how things are being routed to your MVC application. Side note: you can include it on the post or not. I am assuming that tutorial just has you using it. Welcome to programming... "more than one way to skin a cat"